# Algebraic statements for morphism of intersection/union/difference of varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm doing [Gathmann's commutative algebra notes](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/commalg-2013/commalg-2013.pdf) Exercise 1.20:

> Let $f: X\to Y$ be a morphism of varieties, and let $Z$ and $W$ be subvarieties of $X$. The
> geometric statements below are then obvious. Find and prove corresponding algebraic statements
> for ideals in rings.
> (a) $f(Z\cup W)=f(Z)\cup f(W)$;
> (b) $f(Z\cap W)⊂ f(Z)\cap f(W)$;
> (c) $f(Z\setminus W)\supset f(Z)\setminus f(W)$.

**Attempt:** Suppose $I(f(Z))=I$ and $I(f(W))=J$, then $I(Z)=I^e$ and $I(W)=J^e$, where $I^e$ and $J^e$ are extensions of $I$ and $J$, hence: $$I(Z\cup W)=I^eJ^e=(IJ)^e,$$ $$I(Z\cap W)=I^e+J^e,$$ $$I(Z\setminus W)=I^e:J^e.$$ Then the statements can be translated to ($I^c$ means the contraction of $I$): $$(a)\quad ((IJ)^e)^c=IJ,$$ $$(b)\quad ((I+J)^e)^c\supset I+J,$$ $$(c)\quad(I^e:J^e)^c⊂I:J.$$
Proof: In exercise 1.19, it was proven that $(I^e)^c\supset I$, so (b) and one direction of (a) are immediate.

**Questions:** Have I translated to the right algebraic statements? How to prove (c) and the other direction of (a)?

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't tag this with algebraic-geometry?

Comment: @KReiser I'm only learning commutative algebra, although in Gathmann's note some geometric intuition is mentioned, but I suppose I could have added it.